# Duplicate resources in android only in release mode?

Tags: android, react-native

I've been trying for several hours trying to fix these duplicate errors which is happening only when I want to build my app for release.

I have react native version 0.71.11
gradle 7.3.1

I run this script

```
"build-release":"react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/ && cd android && ./gradlew clean && ./gradlew assembleRelease && cd ..",
```

and I get errors in

```
    :app:mergeReleaseResources

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png [drawable-xhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png       [drawable-xxhdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-xxhdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-hdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
  [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png   [drawable-mdpi-v4/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon] /path/to/project/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_elements_src_assets_backicon.png: Error: Duplicate resources
```

I checked the resources in the android/app/src/main/res there is no duplicate resource, although the same resources are also in the android/app/build/generated/res/react/release, but they are not duplicate in this folder, I tried deleting from the main and then running the ./gradlew assembleRelease but then it was complaining that it couldn't compile some files.

Any idea what could be wrong?
This is my app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
 * By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
 */
react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native-codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/react-native-codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")

    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]

    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []

    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}

/**
 * Set this to true to create four separate APKs instead of one,
 * one for each native architecture. This is useful if you don't
 * use App Bundles (https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/)
 * and want to have separate APKs to upload to the Play Store.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Private function to get the list of Native Architectures you want to build.
 * This reads the value from reactNativeArchitectures in your gradle.properties
 * file and works together with the --active-arch-only flag of react-native run-android.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.evcharger"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.evcharger"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            // Example: versionCode 1 will generate 1001 for armeabi-v7a, 1002 for x86, etc.
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")

    implementation("androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0")
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0")

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Note that I tried commenting out the buildTypes rules for minification and proguardfiles but no difference

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it temporarily working by uncommenting the debuggable variants list and including my release variant (called "release") into the list.

However, still wasn't able to get it working for a release build.

Comment: I am not sure why, I replaced some images with other files and it started working, the couldn't compile error was related to those files not sure why it couldn't compile

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all drawable-* dirs with the command:

```
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
```

Or, you can delete them manually, going to the path:

```
android/app/src/main/res/
```